# Issue showing multiple labels on a polygon of OpenLayers2

Tags: openlayers-2, sld

I am facing an issue, that I want to show multiple labels on each polygon of OpenLayers.
 I am defining styles in style editor of a layer.like

```
 <sld:Label>
           ogc:PropertyName>XYZ< /ogc:PropertyName>             
 </sld:Label>
```

where xyz is one of the columns in my query. Now I want to show one more column on the polygon from query and the attribute should be one after the other on the polygon.

Answer (score 1):

In general SLD (though I haven't tested it in OpenLayers) you can do:

```
<sld:Label>
       <ogc:PropertyName>XYZ</ogc:PropertyName>             
       <ogc:PropertyName>ABC</ogc:PropertyName>             
 </sld:Label>
```

and they will be concatenated. If you need more than one white space you can play around with a [CDATA] block to contain extra white space.

Comment: Yes. I was using the same way but the second property is comming null from database. Because of this region the entire label is not showing.

Comment: replace the nulls with empty strings

Comment: I need to check whether the property is null. If it is null then need to show NA else the value. How to achieve this in SLD?

Comment: No standard way - if you are using GeoServer check out the functions

Comment: Thanks for your help iant. I have handling null values in the query itself.

Comment: feel free to upvote and accept the question if it helpful